# Como habilitar 2 input text con un select

Tags: javascript, html

necesito habilitar 2 input o mas con un select, logre habilitar uno pero el segundo no me lo habilita. Al seleccionar Transferencia Bancaria me habilita solamente el input id="refer"

Codigo:

```
                <td><label class="control-label">Metodo de Pago</label></td>
                <td><div class="controls">
                    <select type="text" id="methodpayment" name="cmbPayment" onchange="if(this.value=='provincial') {document.getElementById('refer','banco').disabled = false} else {document.getElementById('refer','banco').disabled = true} ">
                        <option value="BLANK">-Seleccione Metodo de Pago- </option>
                        <option value="provincial">Transferencia Bancaria</option>
                        <option>Pago en Efectivo</option>
                        <option>Punto de venta</option>
                    </select><font color="Red"> <b>Seleccione Metodo de Pago</b></font>
                    <input type="text" id="refer" name="transferenciabancaria" size="12"  disabled> <font color="Red"> <b>Escriba acá la referencia Bancaria</b></font>
                   <input type="text" id="banco" name="bancoorigen" size="12"  disabled> <font color="Red"> <b>Banco de Origen</b></font>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        <td><label class="control-label">Metodo de Pago</label></td>
            <td><div class="controls">
                <select type="text" id="methodpayment" name="cmbPayment" 
                 onchange="if(this.value=='provincial') {
                        document.getElementById('refer').disabled = false;
                        document.getElementById('banco').disabled = false;
                    } else {
                        document.getElementById('refer').disabled = true;
                        document.getElementById('banco').disabled = true;
                    } ">
                    <option value="BLANK">-Seleccione Metodo de Pago- </option>
                    <option value="provincial">Transferencia Bancaria</option>
                    <option>Pago en Efectivo</option>
                    <option>Punto de venta</option>
                </select><font color="Red"> <b>Seleccione Metodo de Pago</b></font>
                <input type="text" id="refer" name="transferenciabancaria" size="12"  disabled> <font color="Red"> <b>Escriba acá la referencia Bancaria</b></font>
               <input type="text" id="banco" name="bancoorigen" size="12"  disabled> <font color="Red"> <b>Banco de Origen</b></font>
```